# Sorting function that also works with containers having only forward iterators

Tags: c++, mergesort, iterator

I was playing around with some code trying to implement a sorting algorithm in C++ that also works with singly linked lists. Since the merge routine of mergesort only scans forward, implementing a generic mergesort seemed like the way to go.

In C, I would have implemented it as follows:

> ```
> typedef struct node {
>   int val;
>   struct node *next;
> } node_t;
>
> /* Merges two sorted linked lists placing the result in the
>    first list. The function modifies both lists */
> node_t* merge(node_t *ha, node_t *hb)
> {
>   if(!ha)
>     return hb;
>   if(!hb)
>     return ha;
>
>   node_t *i;
>   node_t *prev;
>   node_t *j = hb;
>
>   prev = NULL;
>   i = ha;
>   while(i || j) {
>     if(!j) break;
>     if(!i) {
>       prev->next = j;
>       break;
>     }
>
>     if(j->val < i->val) {
>       if(!prev)
>         ha = j;
>       else
>         prev->next = j;
>
>       prev = j;
>       j = j->next;
>       prev->next = i;
>     }
>     else {
>       prev = i;
>       i = i->next;
>     }
>   }
>
>   return ha;
> }
>
> node_t* mergesort(node_t *ha)
> {
>   if(!ha || !ha->next)
>     return ha;
>
>   node_t * prev;
>   node_t *mid = ha;
>   node_t *fast = ha;
>
>   /* Find midpoint of linked list */
>   while(1) {
>     fast = fast->next;
>     if(!fast) break;
>     fast = fast->next;
>     if(!fast) break;
>     mid = mid->next;
>   }
>
>   prev = mid;
>   mid = mid->next;
>   prev->next = NULL;
>   ha = mergesort(ha);
>   mid = mergesort(mid);
>   return merge(ha, mid);
> }
> ```

---

Here is my C++ implementation, which I would like to have reviewed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

template<typename InputIt1, typename InputIt2, typename OutputIt>
OutputIt my_merge(InputIt1 first1,
               InputIt1 end1,
               InputIt2 first2,
               InputIt2 end2,
               OutputIt out)
{
  while(first1 != end1) {
    if(first2 == end2)
      return std::copy(first1, end1, out);

    if(*first1 < *first2) {
      *out = *first1;
      ++first1;
    }
    else {
      *out = *first2;
      ++first2;
    }
    ++out;
  }

  return std::copy(first2, end2, out);
}

template<typename InputIt>
void mergesort(InputIt first, InputIt end)
{
  size_t n = std::distance(first, end);
  if(n < 2)
    return;
  InputIt mid = first;

  for(size_t i = 0; i < n/2; ++i)
    ++mid;

  std::vector<typename InputIt::value_type> res;
  mergesort(first, mid);
  mergesort(mid, end);
  my_merge(first, mid, mid, end, std::back_inserter(res));
  std::copy(res.begin(), res.end(), first);
}

int main()
{
  std::list<int> a { 1,2,8,4,2457,5,2,58,3,564,6,7 };
  mergesort(a.begin(), a.end());
  for(auto& i : a)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Questions:

1. Are there any obvious ways of improving my C++ implementation?
2. Are there any possible efficiency improvements? My annoyance is mostly that I walk any list twice for searching the midpoint. Is there a way of doing this without having to manually write a traversal of the list of two iterators, one moving one step at a time and the other two to get the midpoint in one sweep?
3. Do I have to give up generality in C++? I don't see how to do the linear "in-place merge" as with the C implementation unless we specialize. I'm not sure if it's possible to do an in-place merge of two STL lists either, since you don't have direct access to the next and previous pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The loop

  ```
  for(size_t i = 0; i < n/2; ++i)
      ++mid;
  ```

  may and should be replaced with `std::advance(mid, n/2)`

  To answer your question on better ways of finding the midpoint, I don't think it is worthy: it complicates the logic, while the amount of calculation remains the same.
- A condition `if(*first1 < *first2)` breaks the stability of merge sort. This way, if two elements compared equal, the one from the second list would output first. Very standard mistake. To fix, either compare for `<=`, or change the order:

  ```
  if (*first2 < *first1) {
      *out = *first2;
      ++first2;
  } else {
      *out = *first1;
      ++first1;
  ```

Answer (score 4):

`std::distance` may (probably will) be linear for a `std::list`.
You could determine it once and pass it down.
Don't forget that for odd length lists one of them is `n/2` and the other `n/2+1`.

If the list is long allocating a vector may be expensive:

```
std::vector<typename InputIt::value_type> res;
```

You're working recursively remember so will have vectors of size n , n /2 , n/ 4 , .. allocated at the same time so end up with 2*n additional space allocated.
And in fact create and destroy n*n the space (doing two recursions at each step).

You should look at `std::splice` which can be used to transfer between lists without creating or destroying values. That may not sound like a big deal for a storage type of `int` but as a general purpose template could be time consuming. Regardless the container is allocating and deallocating 'links' somewhere back there!

I would at least work 'destructively' removing from one list and adding to the result.

At the end you would have an empty original list and a nicely sorted result. You could then perform an `std::swap(.,.)`.

If you're not prepared to change your function prototype (my idea requires you to pass in the list not just iterators) it is probably still worth copying the values out into a temporary list, doing it my way and copy the values back again!

You can take a bit of pressure off by `reserve(.)` on your vector since you know the required capacity. But as I said, I'm not sure it's right vehicle.